# IE and FF timing out during server request; IIS connection timeout not resolving issue

Tags: iis-6, timeout, connection-timeout

I have a .NET web application that's deployed to IIS6. Our users use IE8, and I've also been debugging this issue with FF 3.6.3. We have a report generation feature that can take a bit of time to complete, lately on average around 3.5 minutes. The problem is that while the report is generating on the server, at about the 2 minute 10 second mark, IE will redirect to "Internet Explorer cannot display the page". In FF, after the same amount of time, it's a blank white page.

While troubleshooting, I came across IIS's connection timeout property, which is 120 seconds by default. That seemed very close to 2 minutes 10 seconds, so I upped it to 5 minutes, but the browsers still redirected after 2 minutes 10 seconds. I then tried lowering the value to 10 seconds in IIS for the website (just to see what would happen), but still the browser redirected after 2 minutes 10 seconds. The connection timeout property does not seem to be doing anything at all, from what I can tell. I tried restarting the website, restarting the app pool, and even restarting IIS, with no change in my results.

My first question is what kind of result the user would see in their browser if IIS was actually enforcing the connection timeout. Would they see the "Internet Explorer cannot display the page" page, or something different?

I have also looked through my web.config for any values that might affect a timeout, but nothing stands out. I'm beginning to worry that there's a browser limit that's been set by group policy in the registry, but I can't be sure because the registry is locked down on end user machines.

Does anyone have any idea why IIS would not be enforcing that timeout limit? Am I looking in the wrong place, or is there another timeout value that could be causing this behavior, perhaps outside IIS completely? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would probably still see the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" page.

The application has its own timeout value, the default being 110 seconds, according to [this msdn topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx). Try changing (or adding) the `executionTimeout` attribute of the `httpRuntime` element in the application's Web.config under `<system.web>`. If you don't have that element you'll have to add it. If you're using ADO.NET you'll also want to check your `commandTimeout` value in your DbCommand/SqlCommand object in your actual code.